# Select one of the radio buttons and click Submit which redirects other url

Tags: jquery

*Script*

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('#conbtn').click(function() {
    if ($('#radio1').is(':checked') $('#radio1').is(':checked') $('#radio1').is(':checked')) {

      $(location).attr('href', 'career-central-choice.html');
    } else {

      alert('Please Select One Stream');

    }
  });
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="select-stream">
    <div class="second_slide">
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="sub_1" id="radio1">
            <label>Science</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sub_1" id="radio2">
            <label>Commerce</label>
            <input type="radio" name="sub_1" id="radio3">
            <label>Humanities/Arts</label>
            <br>
            <button id="conbtn">Continous</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to redirect to another page *on select* using a radio button?

Comment: Why are you using `$('#radio1')` thrice? and show your HTML.

Comment: <div class="select-stream">
    
     <div class="second_slide">
      <form>
       <input type="radio" name="sub_1" id="radio1">
       <label>Science</label>
       <input type="radio" name="sub_1" id="radio2">
       <label>Commerce</label>
       <input type="radio" name="sub_1" id="radio3">
       <label>Humanities/Arts</label><br>
       <button id="conbtn">Continous</button>
      </form>
      
     </div>
    
    </div>

Comment: [CLICK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Your title and your text are two different questions, do you want to redirect after click on a submit button or do you want to redirect after click on a radio button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `||` operator and use correct ID selector.

Use

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#conbtn').click(function() {
        if ($('#radio1').is(':checked') || 
            $('#radio2').is(':checked') || 
            $('#radio3').is(':checked')) {
            $(location).attr('href', 'career-central-choice.html');
        } else {
            alert('Please Select One Stream');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You have #radio2 twice ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($('#radio1').is(':checked')) {
    location.href=/*your url*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add params `<form id="form" action="career-central-choice.html">`.

and in JS:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
$('#form').submit(function() {
    if (!$('#radio1').is(':checked') && 
        !$('#radio2').is(':checked') && 
        !$('#radio3').is(':checked')) {
        alert('Please Select One Stream');
        return false; // this row disables form sending
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined